# Android: Updating things while using recycler view with grid layout

Tags: android

I am using a recycler view with grid layout.(Grid layout is necessary for me)
When i do a search, the results are shown in adaptor like below:

[image: a]
When the invalid thing is searched, then following is shown
It looks very weird. I want to display the "No result found" image in whole screen.
How can i achieve that:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way to achieve this is
hiding the GridView and show another hidden View to display this.

you can check if the search result is empty, then set the grid view invisible:

```
gridview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

And then set the message view to visible

```
noResultView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: or you can choose to hide the recycler view.

Comment: I think hiding recycler view is a good solution for me .... can you explain abit how to achieve that?

Comment: I suppose you already have some code for checking if the search result is empty, and I think you can add something like the following:


 `if(result == null){
noResultView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
gridview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}else{
noResultView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
gridview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
adapter.notifydatasetchanged()
} `